# Tizen samsung wear bluetooth access

Tags: bluetooth, tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk

I am attempting to access the Bluetooth API in the Samsung wear IDE for the Gear 2. I have successfully added the WIDLPROCXML definitions from the normal IDE to the Wear IDE and can have access on content assist to all the `tizen.bluetooth.xx` functions.

In the Wear IDE on the `app.js` file below, the console results undefined when calling the `bluetooth.address` function. I am aware that Tizen intentionally is trying to disallow access to Bluetooth to keep their watch only on the Samsung devices, but being an open platform I would like to make my own application communicate with other Bluetooth devices (i.e. iPhone, other radios) etc.

Any advice on how I can get access to the full Bluetooth API would be helpful. I wonder if it has something to do with the Application Control Engine on the Web Run Time vs a config file that can be altered on the device. I know access to Bluetooth is possible as Samsung has their own API for connecting to their galaxy devices.

Below is the sample app and the console output:

```js
var adapter = tizen.bluetooth.getDefaultAdapter();
var deviceCapabilities;

deviceCapabilities = tizen.systeminfo.getCapabilities();

if (deviceCapabilities.bluetooth)
{
    console.log("Bluetooth is supported");
}

console.log(adapter.address);

adapter.setPowered(true);

console.log(deviceCapabilities.platformName);


adapter.setPowered(false, successCallback, errorCallback)
```

Console Output:

```
js/app.js (9) :Bluetooth is supported
js/app.js (12) :undefined
js/app.js (16) :Tizen
js/app.js (19) :NotSupportedError: Bluetooth turn off is not supported
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short: you can't.

Bluetooth capabilities are not exposed to JavaScript on wearable profile, so you cannot access them.
This is not only matter of ACE or WRT "blocking: your access, at the moment WRT just lacks this capability on wearables.

Comment: Can you answer why certain Bluetooth API functions work and other's do not? Specifically the setPower(true function works as other will not DiscoverDevices, etc?  Also can I access Bluetooth through the system bus or session bus from the wear IDE? How does Samsung access the Bluetooth from their Accessory Protocol?

Comment: They do not work, because they are not supported - which means that there is no working implementation of this, and JS->C/C++ layer throws the `NotSupportedError`. I don't know why such decision has been made, I may suspect that there might have been some use cases where it was important, that bluetooth is always on (important for leader-follower apps). And of course some Samsung applications work outside of WRT as native apps, or are given more privileges in other way (there are few layers, WRT/ACE, filerights, SMACK).