# Tizen send data from wearable to android phone and also from phone to wearable

Tags: bluetooth, tizen

I need to send some binary files via bluetooth from tizen g2 watch to android phone and then from phone to watch, as I've searched it I can't [implement bluetooth in js files](https://developer.tizen.org/ko/development/tutorials/web-application/tizen-features/network/bluetooth?langredirect=1) as said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25111725/tizen-samsung-wear-bluetooth-access) so what is the most straightforward way to do it? can we use tizen wearable debug over bluetooth instead? is it applicable in this case?
I'm new to tizen so I feel confused and I really appreciate any advice about this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can develop companion app using Samsung Accessory Protocol(SAP) in this scenario. Please go through [this link](http://developer.samsung.com/gear/develop/samples/companion) to know more. If you are trying to develop the tizen part in web, then have a look in the **File Transfer** sample of **web** section. There're separate applications for sending and receiving files from tizen to android and vice versa. You can combine those to implement the bidirectional communication.

Comment: Thank you. The link you mentioned was pretty useful but the only problem is that my version is 2.2 but those codes are not for 2.2, I tried to import them in a 2.2 wearable app but I face errors for package installation on gear 2 watch when I try to run, do you have any ideas how I can fix it? What changes are needed for those codes to be compatible with tizen 2.2?

Comment: Did you try changing the api version from 2.3.1 to 2.2 in the manifest file? Also make sure that you've installed packages for the particular sdk version before.